# Spark structured streaming - how to queue bytes value to Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm writing a Spark application that uses structured streaming. The app reads messages from a Kafka topic `topic1`, constructs a new message, serializes it to an `Array[Byte]` and publishes them to another Kafka topic `topic2`.

The serializing to a byte array is important because I use a specific serializer/deserializer that the downstream consumer of `topic2` also uses.

I've trouble producing to Kafka though. I'm not even sure how to do so..there's only plenty of examples online about queueing JSON data.

The code -

```
case class OutputMessage(id: String, bytes: Array[Byte])

implicit val encoder: Encoder[OutputMessage] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo

val outputMessagesDataSet: DataSet[OutputMessage] = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
  .select($"value")
  .mapPartitions{r =>
     val messages: Iterator[OutputMessage] = createMessages(r)
     messages
  }

outputMessagesDataSet
  .writeStream
  .selectExpr("CAST(id AS String) AS key", "bytes AS value")
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1")
  .option("topic", "topic2")
  .option("checkpointLocation", loc)
  .trigger(trigger)
  .start
  .awaitTermination
```

However, that throws exception `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'id' given input columns: [value]; line 1 pos 5;`

How do I queue to Kafka with `id` as the key and `bytes` as the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EmiCareOfCell44 suggested, I printed out the schema -

If I do `messagesDataSet.printSchema()` then I get only one value with `binary` type. But if I do

```
val df = spark.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server1")
.option("subscribe", "topic1")
.load()

df.printSchema()
```

Then it prints

```
 root
  |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
  |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
  |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
  |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
  |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
  |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
  |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

But the Dataframe hasn't undergone the transformation that is needed, which is done in

```
.mapPartitions{r =>
 val messages: Iterator[OutputMessage] = createMessages(r)
 messages
}
```

It looks like the Dataset's value has only one binary value.

I searched for some answers here, then found this post - [Value Type is binary after Spark Dataset mapGroups operation even return a String in the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658610/value-type-is-binary-after-spark-dataset-mapgroups-operation-even-return-a-strin)

I had an Encoder set up -

```
implicit val encoder: Encoder[OutputMessage] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo
```

That was causing the value to be converted into binary. Since `OutputMessage` is a scala class, the Encoder isn't required, so I removed it. After that, printing out the schema showed two fields (String and bytes which is what I wanted). After that, line `.selectExpr("CAST(id AS String) AS key", "bytes AS value")` worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the schema of the dataframe that "collects" the message. As you are collecting only the "value" field, incoming events arrive in the following form:

```
    +-------------------+
    | value             |
    +-------------------+
    | field1,field2,..  |
    +-------------------+
```

Yo need to query for the key as well like in the Spark documentation:

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

or

```
df.select(col("key").cast(StringType), col("value").cast(StringType))
```